# Azure table entity model design

Tags: azure, database-design, model, entity

In most examples of table entity models I see something like:

```
public class CustomerEntity : TableEntity
{
    public CustomerEntity(string lastName, string firstName)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = lastName;
        this.RowKey = firstName;
    }

    public CustomerEntity() { }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

As we see here `lastname` and `firstname` used as partition key and row key accordingly. So later after saving and retrieving an entity I can access those info from `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` properties. But what if I want to send this model to client side later as json, I suppose `PartitionKey` and `RowKey`  of TableEntity base class would not be serialized. So if i add `LastName` and `FirstName` as properties to model, then unnecessary data duplication will occur in storage. What is the best way avoid data duplication in storage and in the same time have an access to lastname and firstname after model been serialized.

Comment: Why do you think `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` would not be serialized?

Comment: I remember we use [DataMember] attribute to contol whether to serialize the model property it seem that in web api it is unnecessary...

Comment: You've probably already considered this, but with this design you can only have one customer with the same name.  If you have two customers with the common name "Chris Williams" for example, this will fail as the combination of PartitionKey and RowKey must be unique.

Comment: Your question is misleading at the least.[DataMember] attribute is relevant for WCF and Data Contract serialization. From your comment above it sounds like you are not even using WCF so you should not have an issue in serialization. It would be better if you updated your question to clarify this and in fact remove the question since the fictitious problem does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use a getter method on your class to avoid confusion:

```
public class CustomerEntity : TableEntity
{
    public CustomerEntity(string lastName, string firstName)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = lastName;
        this.RowKey = firstName;
    }

    public CustomerEntity() { }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get { return this.RowKey; } }

    public string LastName { get { return this.PartitionKey; } }

}
```

Or, you could map the data to an anonymous object in your API and return that via JSON:

```
var customerJson = new
{
    Firstname = customer.RowKey,
    LastName = customer. PartitionKey,
    customer.Email,
    customer.PhoneNumber
};
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customerJson);
```

Comment: Thanks. But will then data be duplicated? i mean columns in storage table for FirstName and LastName will be created with same values as PartitionKey and RowKey?

Comment: For any property that should be stored in the Table service, the property must be a public property of a supported type that exposes both get and set. Also, your entity type must expose a parameter-less constructor. Easiest way to find out is to give it a try.  See updated answer for mapping option.